# Is the infinite regular tree $T_\infty$ quasi-isometric to the $n$-regular tree $T_n$?

Tags: trees, geometric-group-theory

It is known that for $n\geq 3$ all $n$-regular trees $T_n$ are quasi-isometric to each other. This can e.g. be seen by using an edge contraction argument.
Is there also a quasi-isometry between the countably infinite regular tree $T_\infty$ and some $T_n$?

Comment: No, that would be impossible. The question is, what quasi-isometry invariants do you know? Do you know about growth? About ideal boundaries of Gromov-hyperbolic spaces? Either one can be used to prove non-existence of a quasiisometry.

Comment: As far as I know the QI-invariant 'growth' is only defined for finitely generated groups and can thus not be applied to $T_\infty$ or is there a more general notion that I am missing? And isn't the boundary of all those trees a Cantor set? I do not yet see a contradiction to the existence of a QI.

Comment: You can define growth in greater generality. The ideal boundaries of the trees of infinite valence will not be compact.

Comment: See §3Db in https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3796: $T_n$ is coarsely proper while $T_\infty$ is not. Coarsely proper seems to be equivalent to the notion of finite packing mentioned by @MoisheCohen. It's reasonable to say that a space that is not coarsely proper has growth $=\infty$ (=greater than any function) and this is a coarse invariant.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, it is an equivalent notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest argument that $T_n$ and $T_\infty$  are not quasiisometric is based on growth, more precisely, it is a fragment the same proof that shows that growth is quasiisometry-invariant:

Every finite valence graph has the "finite packing" property: There exists $\rho\ge 0$ such that for every $R\ge r\ge \rho$, every ball $B(x,R)$  contains only finitely many pairwise disjoint balls of the radius $r$. (One can even take $\rho=0$ for graphs of finite valence.) In fact, if the valence is uniformly bounded like in your case, then the number of such $r$-balls is also uniformly bounded by a function of $R$ and $r$.

The finite packing property is easily seen to be quasiisometry-invariant: If $X_1, X_2$ are quasiisometric metric spaces and $X_1$ has finite packing property then $X_2$ does as well. The finite packing property is clearly false for regular trees of infinite valence.